# Window operation in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I didn't understand the state in the window process. For example;

```scala
val sums = levels.
  groupBy(window($"time", "5 seconds")).
  agg(sum("level")).show()
```

1. According to the code above, does Spark only keep states in the last 5 seconds?
2. Are old states being deleted in each windowing operation?
3. Where do the windowing states held? Memory?

And, with watermarking, are old states being deleted in each grouping operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. According to the code above, does Spark only keep states in the last 5 seconds?

It depends on which semantic you use: if you're using processing time, yes it is. If you're using event time, windows in state will be evicted when watermark passes by its end timestamp, so if you allow 7 days late events, windows in state will evict after 7 days.

> 2. Are old states being deleted in each windowing operation?

Eviction (deletion of windows in state) will be happened for each batch.

> 3. Where do the windowing states held? Memory?

For Apache Spark, a hashmap in executor holds the Key/Value pairs of states. In fact, Spark holds multiple versions (batch) of state, so you may need to consider higher size of memory being occupied. In worst case, it can theorically occupy 100x of memory than a version of state. (This will be remedied in Spark 2.4.0.)

Databricks states their product leverages RocksDB which avoids keeping them all in heap memory.

> And, with watermarking, are old states being deleted in each grouping operation?

Eviction happens on stateful operation regardless of the semantic: processing time vs event time.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. In many case, are there operations make according to event time with watermark?

Comment: I’m not sure I get you correctly, but “withWatermark” with timestamp column, and then window function with timestamp column in group by. That’s all.

Comment: Great! Happy to help.